# Define $_POST variable before form submission

Tags: php, html

How can I define my `$_POST` variables in below sample code before submission to prevent PHP Undefined index notice.
HTML sample code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my php sample code:

```
$post_variable = $_POST["my_input"];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do some searching on SO? There are loads of questions about your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check that the post variable exists before trying to access it:

```
$value1 = isset($_POST["my_input"]) ? $_POST['my_input'] : false;
```

now, if my_input is set in the post $value1 will contain it, otherwise it will be false

Answer (score 0):

No, they're set on the server side in case of a POST request so you can't really set them before the request is sent

However, what you can do is this

```
if(isset($_POST["my_input"])) $value1 = $_POST["my_input"];
```

This makes sure that the value is set in the POST array before assigning it to a variable and thus removing the error of the undefined index